# Is there an easy way to model a heart shape in 3D?

Tags: 3d, modeling

I want to model a heart shape in 3D with as little code needed as possible and without using external model files.

In 2D, I can use some Bézier curves to draw a heart shape, and I could extrude this to get a simple 3D heart shape, but this doesn't look like the shape I want. The bottom of the heart should be a peak, the upper part should be two rounded parts (well, I guess you know what I mean).

So, is there an easy way to model such a shape in 3D (i.e., a simple formula or a small code snippet)?

Comment: There are many 3D interpretations of the "standard" 2D heart.  A direct projection produces a "flat" 3D heart similar to valentine candy boxes.  You can have two pseudo-hemisphere lobes at the top, or one with a dimple (like the top of an apple).  Be more specific, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page at MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html) had some nice material. Although mostly in 2D it did show a couple of 3D shapes too. It has a link to [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartSurface.html), which seems very promising.

Comment: Which, in turn, has a reference to http://jalape.no/math/hearttxt containing a povray model for a heart

Answer (score 1):

I think your direction is good.

Model a 2D heart and extrude it to the maximal width you want.

You can now apply additional transformation that will scale the width differently along the height.

You can do that using a Bézier curve to form the desired scale for each location along the height.